# How to compare two numbers using only Boolean or fuzzy logic - No < or > allowed

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba

Given variables a and b, determine which one is the bigger one using only Boolean. Is that possible? 
No Great than ">" or Less "<" than signs are allowed.
Is this even possible?

Some people didn't understand what I was asking, even though I saw a couple of smart and interesting solutions already, such as checking for the negative sign on a string... :-)

So, the question may be re-written in the following way...
given two numeric variables, determine which of them contains the bigger value without using < or > and using only boolean operators (AND, OR, XOR, NOT, etc.)

Thanks for those who answered...

Comment: What do you mean using only boolean? Please edit your question so that someone other then yourself can undestand it.

Comment: Would you improve the question? It is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same theory as @Nizam, but I'm pretty sure Math.Min uses greater than and less than. You can use purely bitwise operators instead and test to see if the sign bit flipped.

**C#**

```
static bool GreaterThan(this int test, int other)
{
    return ((test - other) & ~0x7FFFFFFF) == 0;
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
<Extension()>
Function GreaterThan(ByVal test As Integer, other As Integer) As Boolean
    Return ((test - other) And Not &H7FFFFFFF) = 0
End Function
```

Unclear if it's "fuzzy" though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question, you could try using Min function

```
If Math.Min(a-b, 0) = 0 Then
   ' a >= b
Else
   ' a < b
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nizam's solution will work and is the most elegant while @Frère Chloé's won't, and you risk a division by zero. Well, of course mine is awful ! but it works!

```
If InStr(Cstr(a - b), "-") Then
Debug.Print "b>a"
Else
Debug.Print "b<=a"
End If
```

Comment: ah okay, I think I've got it, in fact  @Frère Chloé's solution doesn't work at all ! you'd better downvote him !

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think it's because of: 1) InStr returns the position of the char inside the string, not a boolean; 2) Converting a number to string to search for the "-" sign? Really risky and not elegant, no developer would understand it at first sight.

Comment: yes you're right on the 2 points, (upvote for you :) that's why I said it was awful. However does it really deserve a downvote?

Comment: Users read the content and decide if upvote, downvote or doing nothing. In this case, apparently someone didn't like the solution and thought about downvoting: it's a right of everyone, we cannot really say if it "deserves or not"... sure he/she could have left a comment if thinking the content could have been improved.